# Hangout OAuth - Invalid Scope : Some requested scopes cannot be shown

Tags: google-oauth, hangouts-api

I am facing the below error while generating token for service account for the Hangout Scope - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot.

Where i receive 400 response code after making a post request to this url -

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

the params are
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
httpMode:POST
body:grant_type=jwt-bearer&assertion=assertion-token

**Note:This was completely working fine. Suddenly am facing this issue.**

cross verified: jwt generation,service_account_id and etc...

**Error Response :** { "error": "invalid_scope",   "error_description": "Some requested scopes cannot be shown": [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot]}

code for generating assertion:

```
 //FORMING THE JWT HEADER
            JSONObject header = new JSONObject();
            header.put("alg", "RS256");
            header.put("typ", "JWT");
            //ENCODING THE HEADER
           String encodedHeader = new String(encodeUrlSafe(header.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));


            //FORMING THE JWT CLAIM SET
            JSONObject claimSet = new JSONObject();
            claimSet.put("iss","123@hangout.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
            claimSet.put("sub","one@domain.com");
            claimSet.put("scope","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot");
            claimSet.put("aud","https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token");
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            claimSet.put("exp",time+3600);
            claimSet.put("iat",time);
            //ENCODING THE CLAIM SET
            String encodedClaim = new String(encodeUrlSafe(claimSet.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));

            //GENERATING THE SIGNATURE
            String password = "secretofkey", alias = "privatekey";
            String signInput = encodedHeader + "." + encodedClaim;
            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
           
            String filepath =   "/check/PrivateKeys/hangoutPKEY.p12";
            KeyStore kstore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            fis = new FileInputStream(filepath);
            kstore.load(fis, password.toCharArray());
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pke = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) kstore.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password.toCharArray()));
            PrivateKey pKey = pke.getPrivateKey();
            signature.initSign(pKey);
            signature.update(signInput.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            String encodedSign = new String(encodeUrlSafe(signature.sign()), "UTF-8");

            //JWT GENERATION
            String JWT = signInput + "." + encodedSign;
  String grant_type = URLEncoder.encode("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
            reqBody = "grant_type=" + grant_type + "&assertion=" + JWT;  

 public static byte[] encodeUrlSafe(byte[] data) {
        Base64 encoder = new Base64();
        byte[] encode = encoder.encodeBase64(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < encode.length; i++) {
            if (encode[i] == '+') {
                encode[i] = '-';
            } else if (encode[i] == '/') {
                encode[i] = '_';
            }
        }
        return encode;
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea, where am going wrong?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? Also, have you checked if the token needs to be renewed?

Comment: hi @Kessy,
Also, have you checked if the token needs to be renewed?
Can you let me know, how this should be done?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests), you should request the access token using this URL instead `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`. Can you try with that one?

Comment: @lamlichus the same error is returned.
{
  "error": "invalid_scope",
  "error_description": "Some requested scopes cannot be shown: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot]"
}

Comment: I tried reproducing this, but I'm getting the token successfully, using both the URL you are using and the one I've suggested. In that case, can you check whether Chat API is enabled for your GCP project? Also, not sure if relevant, but `grant_type` value should be `urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer` according to the docs. And last but not least, consider providing the code you are using to generate the assertion, how you are calling the URL, etc.

Comment: @lamblichus, thanks for reply.
I have tried cross checked the Chat API is enabled for my GCP. And grant_type value i have used is 
grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
have added code to generate jwt above.

Comment: Hi, after you posted your code, I noticed what was the issue. I posted an answer explaining this. I hope this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer:

You are trying to use domain-wide authority to impersonate a regular account. This is not supported in Chat API.

#### Issue detail:

You are using the `sub` parameter when building your JWT claim:

```
claimSet.put("sub","one@domain.com");
```

Where `sub` refers to:

> **sub**: The email address of the user for which the application is requesting delegated access.

I noticed that, if I add the `sub` parameter to my test code, I get the same error as you.

#### Solution:

Remove this line from your code in order to authorize with the service account (without impersonation) and handle bot data:

```
claimSet.put("sub","one@domain.com");
```

#### Background explanation:

[Chat API](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/rest-api) can be used for bots to manage their own data, not to manage end-user data. Therefore, you can only use a service account to act as the bot, without impersonating an end-user.

From this Issue Tracker [comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/205606720#comment3):

> At the present moment, Chat API can only be used to manage bot-related data (listing the spaces in which the bot is included, etc.). Using domain-wide delegation to manage regular users' data is not currently possible.

#### Feature request:

If you'd like to be able to access regular users' data with your service account and domain-wide delegation via Chat API, you are not alone. This feature has been requested before in Issue Tracker:

- [Accessing the Google Chats of regular users using domain-wide delegated permission and service account credentials](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/205759602)

I'd suggest you to [star the referenced issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to keep track of it and to help prioritizing it.

#### Reference:

- [Using service accounts](https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/service-accounts#creating_and_using_a_service_account)
- [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)
- [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests)

Comment: @lamblichus, This works really perfect thanks for guiding me. 
this resolved weeks of debugging.